# writing multiple lines to a java file

Tags: java, printing, filewriter, printwriter, writer

I'm trying to create an error report in Java, but the file reader writes over the same line
every time I find a new error, so all that displays is the last error.  How would I prevent this?

```
public void errorReport(String error)
{
    try {

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.write(error);
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

} // end error report

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append text to an existing file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
```

The second argument is "append mode." If it is `true`, then the `FileWriter` will append lines instead of writing over them.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)